# Is it possible to compile a flex project that uses Cairngorm with command line?

Tags: apache-flex, compilation, cairngorm

Has anyone tried to compile a flex project that uses Cairngorm with command line?

Comment: Yes, it's no different from compiling any other flex application from the command line.  What issues are you having?

Comment: Can you provide the steps of compiling flex application from the command line? I'm new to flex,only familiar with flash before.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Cairngorm SWC is in your library path. For instance, if you have the SWC in a folder called "libs" that is relative to the current directory, you should include the following command line argument for mxmlc:

```
--library-path+="libs"
```

Notice the `+=` in there. This means that "libs" is added to the current library path, which may already include other folders. The quotes are optional if you don't have spaces in your path.